# referrer reporting as 'direct' in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

This is for GA v3.

I have a website for a service that allows users to schedule appointments online through a 3rd party app operating under a different domain. The 3rd party app allows me to configure it with my GA tracking ID and registers a few events during the registration process. I'm able to see these events just fine in GA, however when I add the **Full Referrer** dimension to the report, it consistently reports `(direct)`.

There is another website not under my control that also allows users to link to the same 3rd party app's registration page for the same service. When I click the link to schedule an appointment from this website, the referrer reports as expected.

**Each can be seen here:**

- https://www.anupaiv.com/ (the 'BOOK ONLINE' button in the header) - this shows `(direct)` as the Full Referrer - I was expecting `www.anupaiv.com`
- https://www.anupawellness.com/iv-hydration-therapy (the 'schedule your iv therapy' button near the bottom of the page) - this is the one that shows the Full Referrer as `www.anupawellness.com` as expected

I tested (in latest versions of FF and Chrome on Mac) and neither the `role="button"` or the `target="_blank"` attributes in the 1st one seem to be causing the issue. Can anyone tell me why this may be happening? or suggest some additional troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you most likely have the domain `anupaiv.com` in the `Referral Exclusion` list in the Property settings.

This is correct because it avoids self-referral problems.

So your referral would be your domain, since the domain is in the referral exclusion list it doesn't consider it, so without a previous source it's the value of *direct*.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is that the default setting? I'm guessing takibg it off the exclusion list will cause other problems elsewhere? Any suggestions for being able to track that conversion originating from my website?

Comment: Yes, it is a default option. Anyway, to track conversion as you want you should cross-domain the two domains but being a third party service I don't think it's possible.

I don't see applicable solutions, unless the backend of the service offers something advanced. Currently the clientId changes because you are on a different domain so those made on the service will result from another user other than the one who clicked on the button on your site.